# Nested "record" in the table column

Tags: sql, oracle, types

We will call **"pair"** a data type that uses two different data types in its definition
(**"type1"** and **"type2"**, respectively).

Define such a data type, indicate what it represents, and use it by adding a column of this type to one of the tables in the schema.

I thought I would solve the **record** very quickly but it seems I can't use this type of data or I didn't use it properly.

*Any suggestions please?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the question; it would probably be better if you posted your own attempt.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_pair_rec is object
  2    (dob    date,
  3     name   varchar2(10)
  4    );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number,
  3     other  t_pair_rec
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, other) values
  2    (1, t_pair_rec(date '2020-01-28', 'Littlefoot'));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID OTHER(DOB, NAME)
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 T_PAIR_REC('28.01.20', 'Littlefoot')

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just didn't think about the object type, because I used it a few times.  Believe me, I tried, I don't try to solve a problem without making an effort. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.